# For a sequence, why must $\lim _{n→∞} {||x_n||} = ∞$, $\lim _{n→∞} {||x_n||} = 0$, or there exists a convergent subsequence with a nonzero limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

Suppose I've got a sequence of vectors $\{x_n\}_{n∈N}$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Why is it that exactly one of the following three facts must hold:

$\lim
_{n→∞}
{||x_n||} = ∞$, 
$\lim
_{n→∞}
{x_n} = 0$, or there exists a convergent subsequence with a nonzero limit?

My progress is that if I have a sequence, then it must either be bounded or not.  If it is not bounded, then by definition there can be no upper bound and so it must be infinite. Then $\lim
_{n→∞}
{||x_n||} = ∞$.  If it is bounded, then by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, we have a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^k$ so it must have a convergent subsequence.  This subsequence either converges to $0$ or it doesn't.  If it does, then we get by definition that $\lim
_{n→∞}
{x_n} = 0$.  If it doesn't, then there exists a convergent subsequence with a nonzero limit.

Am I right?

Comment: No, you are not right. If a sequence is unbounded, it does *not* imply that the limit is $\infty$. $0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,\dots$ is unbounded but it has no limit because some of the entries are stuck at small values while others get arbitrarily large.

Comment: Yeah but if I take the norm of all those and calculate it, it's going to get larger as the largest element of that sequence increases.  That would make the limit of the norm approach infinity.  Why wouldn't it?

Comment: The absolute value or norm may also be zero. But that doesn't matter, the absolute value has no impact on my sequence at all. What you're missing is that the typical hard sequences that you must address don't have any limit at all. You're a priori assuming that a sequence always has some limit which is wrong.

Comment: How would you suggest proving it then?

Comment: The example by  @LubošMotl not only shows that there was something wrong with how you interpreted the problem. It is in fact a counterexample to the very claim itself.

Comment: I didn't come up with the question, I'm trying to solve it. As far as I can tell, "unbounded" means there is no upper bound, by definition.  If @LubošMotl wants to claim that his sequence is unbounded, then there must be an upper bound to it.  It has nothing to do with convergence.

Comment: Dear @Jimm, I agree that my sequence, interpreted e.g. as vectors in $R^1$, is a counterexample, even though I didn't dare to suggest that it could have been so. I think that to show that the proposed lemma is false counts as a solution, too.

Comment: I disagree because as $n$ goes to infinity, a norm defined on $n$ becomes $\|x\|_\infty = \sup_n |x_n|$ by the definition of a norm.  Doesn't that mean that the limit of the norm of @LubošMotl 's sequence has a maximal value approaching infinity?

Comment: @Jimm, something like that could make the proposition right. But where in the world can you define $||x_n||$ as a *supremum* of a set that contains not just $x_n$ but also other $x_{m}$? The norm of a vector $x_n$ is just the Pythagorean etc. length of it, isn't it?

Comment: That's the definition of a norm that my textbook uses and the one on wikipedia here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity)  It's an infinite norm though, as opposed to the $\mathbb{R}^2$ norm, and I didn't realize originally that that's probably what the original asker of the question had to be referring to or the question would be false.

Comment: When you say it (the sequence) has no upper bound then it(...?) must be infinite, what is the second IT? The sequence? Its upper bound? Its limit? If x(2n)=0 and x(2n+1)=n, the sequence is unbounded but does not tend to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that an unbounded sequence must have limit $\infty$: consider the sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $a_{2n}=0$ and $a_{2n+1}=2n+1$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Moreover, this example shows that the proposed result is false: the only convergent subsequences converge to $0$, but the sequence itself does not and also does not diverge to $\infty$.

Comment: I'm confused because as far as I can tell, the norm of that sequence is still getting larger and larger and if it's unbounded, should approach infinity.  The norm as $n$ approaches infinity being defined as the norm of $n$, which becomes the infinity norm, $\|x\|_\infty = \sup_n |x_n|$.  Perhaps that was really unclear and I also didn't realize until now. But that would make it true no?

Comment: @Jimm: No. If $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence of real numbers (e.g., norms of vectors), then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ means that for each $M\in\Bbb R$ there is an $m_M\in\Bbb N$ such that $a_n>M$ for each $m\ge m_M$. That’s clear not the case for this sequence, since every second term is $0$.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the norm of the sequence." SOME of the sequence, a subsequence of the sequence,that is,  exhibits growth, but another subsequence does not. You would not say the sequence approaches infinity when a(n)=0 for infinitely many n, just as you would not say that a sequence approaches the number 4 if infinitely many of its terms are 0.